# Usage of rendered={!! Value} in output panel component

Tags: visualforce, rendered

I'm trying to understand this code, which was written in a custom component for VF page.

I didn't understand the usage of **rendered attribute in output panel** with "**{!!**" . Usually we use only one exclamatory '!' for retrieving the value.

I tried in google, but didn't get any thing regarding this. can someone help me out

```
    <div class="modal fade" style="display: none; width: 70% !important">
          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="header" layout="block" rendered="{!!movingFavoritesBetweenLists}">
              Search and Add Favorites
          </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{!  }` is the merge field syntax which gets the value from the controller. The other `!` is used to negate a Boolean value.

So, in your example, `rendered="{!!movingFavoritesBetweenLists}"` means that the `apex:outputPanel` is rendered if `movingFavoritesBetweenLists` is false.

Comment: Thanks martin. That really didn't strike to my mind.
Once I read your answer, it looks like a small one. Thank you very much..

Comment: @KrishnaN No problem. glad to help.